# I need a formula that will evaluate changes in different sized number equally

Tags: functions

I have 4 different investing schemes. I’m changing universal parameters, back testing, and evaluating the average returns of these 4 schemes.

Unfortunately the “average” performance doesn’t treat each scheme equally because the existing returns are not equal. If one scheme is doing 50% and the others are in the 10% area, changes in the parameters become dominated by the leading scheme and the lesser scheme's progress gets ignored.

I need an index of the 4 that measures each scheme's progress equally.  A 40% increase in any scheme should produce a 10% increase in this index regardless of how far that scheme is ahead of or behind the others.

The average performance would be important for investing. For tuning the system however, I need to see how universal parameter changes affect each scheme and I need a fair index to evaluate and to decide whether to keep these changes or discard them. Is there a formula or a function for such an index?

Thanks much,
roofman6

Answer (score 0):

If $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$ are the scheme's performances before a change and $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ are their performances after a change, then the percentage change in scheme $i$ is $a_i/b_i-1$. So your overall index's increase can be the sum of these, which is
$$
\frac{a_1}{b_1}+\frac{a_2}{b_2}+\frac{a_3}{b_3}+\frac{a_4}{b_4}-4.
$$
Alternatively, you can compute the product
$$
\frac{a_1}{b_1}\frac{a_2}{b_2}\frac{a_3}{b_3}\frac{a_4}{b_4};
$$
an answer of $1$ is the neutral response, and anything larger indicates progress on average.

Comment: Greg,

Thanks for your prompt response. I see now that I didn't state the problem correctly. The situation is that once I change the parameters, I no longer have the previous data to evaluate. I no longer have the "b's", just the new "a's". 

I can see now that what I need cannot be done without a record of the previous data. I've tried to get and Excel add-in called Morecalc Recall to give me that data, but so far no luck.

Thanks again for your kind response,
roofman6